# Exclude some fields from randomization during a generation run

Tags: system-verilog

I wan't to exclude some fields from randomization based on a certain condition that is itself determined during the same randomization run. This means I can't use `rand_mode(0)` as this needs to be called before a call to `randomize()`.

Here's a simple example of what I mean. Let's say I have a class with 2 integer fields and a boolean that decides whether to randomize the second field or to keep its value constant (i.e. the one before a call to `randomize()`):

```
class some_item;
  rand bit do_rand_other_field;
  rand int some_field;
  rand int some_other_field;

  // ...
endclass
```

The only thing I can come up with is to declare an extra local field that will store the value of `some_other_field` before a randomization run:

```
class some_item;
  // ...

  local int some_other_field_init;

  function void pre_randomize();
    some_other_field_init = some_other_field;
  endfunction

  // ...
endclass
```

When `do_rand_other_field` is not true, I just constrain the field to take its initial value:

```
class some_item;
  // ...

  constraint randomize_some_other_field {
    if (!do_rand_other_field)
      some_other_field == some_other_field_init;
  }

  // ...
endclass
```

This works, but if I have many such conditionally randomized fields it can become inefficient to store and copy them all. I could declare these "initial" fields as `static` and this would reduce the memory consumption, but the run-time penalty of copying would still be there.

The randomization engine has to store these values somewhere, since in case of a constraint contradiction it will return the un-randomized object. I'd like to find a way to tap into these value. Is there any feature of the language that I overlooked that could help me do this?

Comment: A running example can be found on EDAPlayground: http://www.edaplayground.com/x/8nS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no feature in SystemVerilog to do what you are asking for without either copying the states you potentially want to maintain, or separating into independent randomizations(separate random class objects or 2-pass on the same object)

The constraint solvers in SystemVerilog work conceptually by constructing the entire solution space first, then randomly picking one of the solutions. You cannot dynamically change the randomness of one of the variables during the solution space building process.

I suppose SystemVerilog could be enhanced so that referring to the previous value of an random variable could be used in a constraint as a state variable, but that would be several years away for you in any case.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, pre/post_randomize are not always called. And also from Mentor Graphics, they suggest to avoid to use them. For your case, is it possible to put the last transaction's value in sequence? Do the normal randomize on sequence item. Then check the field to decide if you need to override another with old value.

Comment: I don't want to do 2 pass randomization.

Comment: Hi @Tudor. Sorry about my poor English and I am not sure what do you mean "2 pass randomization". I just put a modified code here, you can have a look. [http://www.edaplayground.com/x/N4a](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/N4a).

Comment: Two pass randomization means when you randomize part of the object first and afterwards you run the randomization again and randomize it again.

Comment: I checked out your code and it does basically the same (a copy), just that you put the field somewhere else. I'm guessing you're doing it to avoid using `pre_randomize()`. What's not always called is `post_randomize()` (in case the randomization fails). Also, doing it like this is poorly encapsulated. What if I want to randomize the class in some totally different scope?